# Double async loop doesn't wait for the inner loop to resolve the promises

Tags: javascript, supabase

I have a double loop that makes multiple async calls for each cycle of the inner loop. Each cycle of the outer loop can influence the results of the next cycle so I want to make sure every async call is completely finished before starting the next. I've tried using Promise.All but that didn't help me.

```js
    outboundDeliveryContents.forEach(async (machine) => {
      machine.inventoryRefillPlan.forEach(async (dish) => {
        if (dish.added_quantity) {
          const { data: getOldestMealsData, error: getOldestMealsError } =
            await getOldestMeals(dish.added_quantity, dish.dish_id);

          if (getOldestMealsError)
            return { data: null, error: getOldestMealsError };

          console.log(getOldestMealsData);

          const outboundDeliveryMeals = getOldestMealsData.map((meal) => ({
            meal_id: meal.id,
            delivery_id: createOutboundDeliveryData[0].id,
            machine_id: machine.machine.machine_id,
          }));

          const {
            data: assignOutboundDeliveryItemsData,
            error: assignOutboundDeliveryItemsError,
          } = await assignOutboundDeliveryItems(outboundDeliveryMeals);

          console.log(assignOutboundDeliveryItemsData);

          if (assignOutboundDeliveryItemsError)
            return { data: null, error: assignOutboundDeliveryItemsError };
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: don't expect forEach and async/await to work like you think - like, why is `outboundDeliveryContents.forEach(async (machine) => {` async since you never await anything, and actually have nothing TO await anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX So I shoudn't use forEach and make it a normal for loop instead ?

Comment: Did you read the duplicate?

Comment: Yes thanks for the help!